# Weblogic managed server getting disconnecting automatically

Tags: java-7, weblogic-10.x

Weblogic managed server stopped suddenly without printing any log. I checked all weblogic logs as well as managed log find nothing related to shutdown. How to debug the cause for the shutdown

Comment: You should include the exact version of Weblogic plus relevant sections of log files to analyse the case. Are you sure it did not print anything? Could you tell us which log files have you checked?

Comment: Weblogic 10.3 am sure that i didn't print anything in log. I checked weblogic log. Adminserver, weblogicAdmin, stdout stderr log

Comment: @Venkatesh, It is very old question, but did you find out what is causing the issue.